# Set up ejabberd server to chat with other servers

Tags: javascript, xmpp, ejabberd, strophe

I've been working with my chat app in localhost but I now I need to connect and chat to other servers and I'm legit lost.

I've created my own ejabberd client and it works fine in local.

What I need to do is to be able to chat to other computer in my office.
We both have the same public ip, obviously. My next step was going to be trying to create a domain to connect with each other but I need to know first if there's any posibility to do it without domains.

Regards!